# Creating a "reverse templating" system in php

Tags: php, html

This is my example, let's take a really simple web page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title of the page</title>
</head>
<body>
  A simple body text
</body>
</html>
```

i would like to have a template that looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
  {body}
</body>
</html>
```

And by using my function I would like to be able in my code to do something like this :

```
$website = file_get_contents("https://GetMeTheFirstCodeBlock/");
$template = file_get_contents("/MyTemplate");

$tabs = my_function_compare($website, $template);

print($tabs["title"]) //print "Title of the page"
print($tabs["body"])  //print "A simple body text"
```

---

Comment: It seems what you are asking is about DOM parsing, which is fraught with pitfalls.  Good luck..  look at `DomDocument` or `PHPQuery`

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is *parsing* HTML.

However the part with your "template" is not the approach I've seen before. The typical ways to describe what you are looking for when parsing are XPath or CSS expressions.

In my personal experience the most convenient way to approach such task is to use [DomCrawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) component from Symfony.